# multer req file is undefined but why?

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, multer

Can anyone tell me why my req.file is undefined?
I add the content header type,
I add single.photo but I get no data

frontend:

```
## data is equal to this:
Object {
  "filename": "3ccc61e1-3c49-4538-9594-b4987b3fa66f.jpg",
  "type": "image/jpg",
  "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/UNVERIFIED-xxxxx-test/ImagePicker/3ccc61e1-3c49-4538-9594-b4987b3fa66f.jpg",
}

const uploadStory = async data => {
  try {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('photo', data);
    const options = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
        'Accept':'application/json'
      },
      method: 'POST',
      body: form
    };
    const res = await fetch('http://xxxxxxx.xx:3000/createstory', options);
    const out = await res.json();
    return out;
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    return e;
  }
};

export default uploadStory;
```

backend:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    console.log(req);
    cb(null, `${file.filename}-${Date.now()}`)
  }
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage
}).single('photo');

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  upload(req, res, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err)
      return;
    } else if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(req.file);
      console.log('hi')
    }
  });
};
```

..................................
..................................
..................................
..................................

Comment: Your data object doesn't look to be the proper type. It should be either "a USVString or Blob (including subclasses such as File)". Your data object actually looks to be a plain object - ie an Object type.

Comment: @IAmDranged do you have a example?

Comment: An example of what? This is just what the docs for `FormData.append()` say. In other cases, the argument will be assumed to be text data - and as such will be coerced to a string if necessary. The result will end up being exposed on `req.body` on the server-side. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your data object looks like this

```
{
    name: "3ccc61e1-3c49-4538-9594-b4987b3fa66f.jpg",
    type: "image/jpg",
    uri: "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/UNVERIFIED-xxxxx-test/ImagePicker/3ccc61e1-3c49-4538-9594-b4987b3fa66f.jpg",
}
```

In your `data` Object your `key` is `filename` instead of `name`

Change your `upload` to this

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
});
```

And then,

```
module.exports = upload.single('photo'), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body); // Body Here
    console.log(req.file); // File Here
    res.status(500).send('Fetch Completed Successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send('Error');
  }
}
```