# FormData is not working fine with Expo CLI React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, multipartform-data, form-data

recently I got an issue with uploading documents functionality in Expo CLI - React native, the issue is the file is not delivering to the backend like FormData() it arrives in a weird array, not like the website at all, I got the same endpoint connected to React JS project and it works fine and the browser delivers the documents correctly,
But not sure what is wrong with FromData here,
I also tried react-native-fs but it's not compatible with Expo
and here is my code

```
                    let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', doc);
                let token = this.props.user.token;
                let header = { headers: { 'Accept': '*', 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token, 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
                let res = await axios.post(BackendURL+'/porta/files/upload/'+document.projectDocumentId, formData, header);
                if(res.data.success === true){
                    alert('File uploaded successfully');
                    this.props.ReloadData(true);
                }
                console.log(doc);
```

Comment: Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67560499/multer-req-file-is-undefined-but-why/67563619#67563619). Hope it helps

Comment: Did you try from Android device and emulator? And did you try with iOS as well? What do you mean by "weird array"? Should I not be in a byte array format?

Comment: @Saamer Yes it should be like the browser Binary

Comment: and i am using IOS only

Comment: Try it with Android and see if that works. It might be related to the file being of the HEIC format

Comment: Okay how it's gonna work with IOS? if you can help me I am willing to pay as i can 
@Saamer contact me on me@mo-webdev.com if you can figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been solved,
the problem where in the header, i removed the content type & accept like this

```
                    let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', {
                    name: doc.name,
                    uri: doc.uri,
                    type: "application/pdf"
                });
                this.props.loadingStatus(true); 
                let token = this.props.user.token;
                let header = { headers: {  'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token } };
                let res = await axios.post(BackendURL+'/portal/files/upload/'+document.projectDocumentId, formData, header);
```